# What is the にはな used for in the following sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は

> 「僕にはな、ちゃんとした名前が……」

Is the above にはな made from the に+は particles with a ない (omitted い), or is it something else entirely?

Context provided below if it will help in solving the above issue.

> Character A:「変な呼び方しないでくれよ！」
>
> 僕はいい加減苛立ちを抑えきれず、そう怒鳴りつけてしまった。
>
> Character A:「僕にはな、ちゃんとした名前が……」

Comment: Since a good answer has already been posted by @Chocolate, I will say this here. 「僕には**な**、ちゃんとした名前が……」 and 「僕には**ない**、ちゃんとした名前が……」 mean completely opposite things.   Former means "I have a proper name." and the latter, "I don't have a proper name."  「ない」 cannot be shortened to 「な」 like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 僕には**な**、ちゃんとした名前が...

The な is a particle. It's used as a filler here.

This person is trying to say something like:

> 僕には(な)、ちゃんとした名前が**ある**(んだ)。

XXに(は)YYがある means "There's YY in XX" / "XX has YY".